# How can I access a separate camera class dynamically in python with kivy (without pre-initialising camera)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, opencv, kivymd

I have written a camera access class using python+kivy (kivycamera.py) and it is working.
**kivycamera.py**

```
# from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton
import time


# class KivyCamera(MDApp):
class KivyCamera(Image):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

        self.image = Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)

        self.start_camera_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text="START CAMERA",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.4, None),
            # size=("100dp", "100dp")
        )
        self.start_camera_button.bind(on_press=self.start_camera)
        layout.add_widget(self.start_camera_button)

        self.save_img_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text="TAKE PICTURE",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.4, None),
            # size=("100dp", "100dp")
        )
        self.save_img_button.bind(on_press=self.take_picture)
        layout.add_widget(self.save_img_button)

        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0 / 30.0)
        # return layout
        # return self.image

    def start_camera(self, *args):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0 / 30.0)
        pass

    def load_video(self, *args):
        check, frame = self.video.read()
        if check:
            x, y, w, h = 200, 200, 250, 250
            p, q, r, s = 220, 220, 210, 210
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (p, q), (p + r, q + s), (255, 0, 0), 3)
            self.image_frame = frame
            buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
            image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.image.texture = image_texture

    def take_picture(self, *args):
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        cv2.imwrite("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr), self.image_frame)
        cv2.imshow("Hi", self.image_frame)

# KivyCamera().run()
```

How can I add this class to another MDApp or Screen only when it is required. I tried below approaches and those were not successful. Do not pre-initialise camera. Only activate camera using a button action.

**Inside a separate MDApp**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivycamera import KivyCamera


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    pass
    # def build(self):
    #     self.camera = KivyCamera()
    #     self.camera.build()
    #     print(self.camera)
    #     return self.camera


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Kivy File

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Hello'
    KivyCamera:
```

**or inside a separate screen using screen manager**

```
class UploadScreen(Screen):
    pass
    # def build(self):
    #     self.my_camera = KivyCamera()
    #     self.my_camera.build()
    #     self.ids.my_camera = self.my_camera
    #     return self.my_camera
```

Kivy File

```
<UploadScreen>:
    name: 'upload'
    KivyCamera:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `KivyCamera` extends `Image`, but you are using the `KivyCamera` as a widget container. Also, in your `build()` method, you are creating a `layout`, but not doing anything with it. I suggest modifying `KivyCamera` definition to change its base class to some `Layout` (I chose `RelativeLayout`) and to add the `layout` as a child. Here is a modified version of your code that does this:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivycamera import KivyCamera


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.camera = KivyCamera()
        self.camera.build()
        print(self.camera)
        return self.camera


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

and kivycamera.py:

```
# from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton
import time


# class KivyCamera(MDApp):
class KivyCamera(RelativeLayout):  # make this a container
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

        self.image = Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)

        self.start_camera_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text="START CAMERA",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.4, None),
            # size=("100dp", "100dp")
        )
        self.start_camera_button.bind(on_press=self.start_camera)
        layout.add_widget(self.start_camera_button)

        self.save_img_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(
            text="TAKE PICTURE",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.4, None),
            # size=("100dp", "100dp")
        )
        self.save_img_button.bind(on_press=self.take_picture)
        layout.add_widget(self.save_img_button)
        self.add_widget(layout)  # add the layout to the GUI

        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0 / 30.0)
        # return layout
        # return self.image

    def start_camera(self, *args):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0 / 30.0)
        pass

    def load_video(self, *args):
        check, frame = self.video.read()
        if check:
            x, y, w, h = 200, 200, 250, 250
            p, q, r, s = 220, 220, 210, 210
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (p, q), (p + r, q + s), (255, 0, 0), 3)
            self.image_frame = frame
            buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
            image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.image.texture = image_texture

    def take_picture(self, *args):
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        cv2.imwrite("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr), self.image_frame)
        cv2.imshow("Hi", self.image_frame)

# KivyCamera().run()
```

There are several other simplifications that you could make. For example, you could eliminate the `build()` method by changing it to an `__init__()` method (must add a `super(KivyCamera, self).__init__()` call), and eliminate the `layout` variable by making `KivyCamera` extend `MDBoxLayout`.

Comment: Thank you very much [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson).  It worked as expected. Your help is very much appreciated